# How to access a variable from button_Click event in windows form application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

I am currently working on a windows form application where I have to store image into local directory and the image into SqlServer database. On the main form, I have used a browse image button which show file dialog on click. Both the image name and path are stored in two separate strings which I have to access from another method that actually stores both the title and image path along with some other data into the database.

I have used the following code on the browse image button.

```
private void btnBrowseImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string saveDirectory = @"D:\ProductImages\";

        OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            if(!Directory.Exists(saveDirectory))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(saveDirectory);
            }

            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileDialog.FileName);
            string fileSavePath = Path.Combine(saveDirectory, fileName);
            File.Copy(fileDialog.FileName, fileSavePath, true);

            string imgTitle = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
            string imgPath = fileSavePath;
        }
    }
```

Now, I want to access both the two variables holding the file name and file path respectively from my Add To Database button. I am passing these two variable along with productName, unitPrice and quantity to AddProduct method in my Products call where they will actually be added to the database as illustrated in the btnAddToDatabase_Click event.

```
private void btnAddToDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string productName, unitPrice, quantity, image, imageTitle;

        productName = txtProductName.Text.Trim();
        unitPrice = txtUnitPrice.Text.Trim();
        quantity = txtQuantity.Text.Trim();
        image = 
        imageTitle = 

        Products.AddProduct(productName, quantity, unitPrice);
        FillGrid();
        btnClearFields_Click(sender, e);

    }
```

I have tried a lot but no luck as these variables cannot be accessed directly from browse button event so that I can locate them where I want. Is there any way that can help me without any failure?

Comment: Your variables need to be scoped as public properties at the class level...method level vars cannot be accessed and might even be garbage collected

Comment: Declare `string imgTitle` and `string imgPath` as private variables outside the method

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare the variables in the class rather than the specific method, then they will have class level scope

```
public class YourClass
{
    private string fileName 
    private string filePath

    private void btnBrowseImage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // code here
        fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileDialog.FileName);
        filePath= Path.Combine(saveDirectory, fileName);
    }

    private void btnAddToDatabase_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // code here
        fileName = "something";
        filePath="something";
    }
    // other methods
}
```